# CheckPoint SSL and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpn, remote-desktop, ssl

I have the following issue. In our company we use Checkpoint endpoint client. However I started using Ubuntu 14.04 and since there is no client for it I need to log into the SSL Portal. Once I log in and press Connect so to connect to the SSL VPN a new window appears saying that Java is not installed. However, I have installed a few different JAVAs , including ORacle one v.8.
Then I can browse intranet sites but I cannot make Rremote desktop to different server in the organization.
Checking with ifconfig shows an ip only from a 192.168.x.x network. As far as I know I need to have also another network adapter with address from 172.x.x.x something network.

I'm sorry If I haven't explained the best way, but I'm new into Linux systems, 
I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you!